# Datastage v9.1 - run user defined sql query file using odbc connector

Tags: datastage

I want to execute multiple lines of DDL and DML commands from a file in datastage.

I have used the ODBC connector with the write mode selected as user defined SQL and the and the SQL statements are available in the file.

But the connector stage is not executing the file. If anyone can provide me with guidance it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide the more details on how you were using the 'DDL & DML statements in the file, warning messages & ODBC configuration etc.. It will help anyone to provide some suggestions- It will save your time as well to resolve it.